# very basic question on extracting data from .tif raster layer in R- projection not in lat/long

Tags: raster, r, extract

I have data on N deposition in the US, which can be found in a `.tif` file from a zipped directory, which can be accessed here: `nadp.sws.uiuc.edu/maplib/grids/2006/TotalN_dep_2006.zip`.

I loaded the data into R using the `raster` package:

```
require(raster)
r <- raster('/path/to/dep_totalN_2006.tif')
```

I then have some coordinates for which I would like to extract values from the raster. Here are 6 sites for testing, in dput format:

```
test.dat <- structure(list(latitude = c(46.414597, 46.137664, 42.258794, 
44.287538, 46.567187, 46.205438), longitude = c(-86.030373, -85.990492, 
-85.847991, -85.806588, -87.954285, -87.481934)), .Names = c("latitude", 
"longitude"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 6L))
> test.dat
  latitude longitude
1 46.41460 -86.03037
2 46.13766 -85.99049
3 42.25879 -85.84799
4 44.28754 -85.80659
5 46.56719 -87.95428
6 46.20544 -87.48193
```

Generally, extracting data is pretty straightforward from this point on. I would grab data from the layer for these point using something like this:

```
points         <- cbind(test.dat$longitude,test.dat$latitude)
test.dat$out   <- extract(r, points)
```

This doesn't work however. It does not error, it just produces a vector of NA values. I can plot the raster layer, which gives a clue to whats going wrong:

```
plot(r)
```

[image]

Clearly the x/y coordinates of the raster layer are not in latitude/longitude, and I expect this is why my `extract` command fails to extract any data from the layer for my list of points. Apologies if this is very basic and has been answered elsewhere, but my searching hasn't yielded a simple answer that came across clearly. I'm experienced with R, but very light on my use of spatial data within R. How can I accurately project the raster file, `r` such that my call to `extract` generates the appropriate values for my sites within `test.dat` based on their latitude/longitude?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to transform your points to the coordinate system of the raster. You could warp the raster to your points' coordinate system but warping rasters is a bit messy.

First create a SpatialPoints object from your coordinates and tell R it is in lat-long coordinates (4326):

```
library(raster);library(sp);library(rgdal) 
pts2 = SpatialPoints(points,proj4string=CRS("+init=epsg:4326"))
```

Then transform to whatever projection the raster is:

```
pts3 = spTransform(pts2, projection(r))
```

To see what these coordinates now are:

```
coordinates(pts3)
     coords.x1 coords.x2
[1,]  767147.2   2643127
[2,]  773433.6   2612906
[3,]  830493.9   2184259
```

And now sample:

```
> extract(r, pts3)
[1] 3.803773 3.885270 6.959986 6.394814 3.374275 3.836861
```

You could also plot them over the raster now:

```
plot(r)
plot(pts3, add=TRUE)
```

should show that.

Comment: The number that you extract what is it? Is the elevation number?